# Database Connector Error in Crystal Report

Tags: crystal-reports, connection, odbc, ms-access-2007, crystal-reports-xi

Now I am using crystal report xi release 2 and microsoft access 2007 Database.
the database have custom function. the main problem of this topic is that custom function of access database.

Comment: Can you please attach the error message or screenshot.

Comment: if could I upload screenshot ! i will be able to success to understand you! but I can not upload a picture

Comment: database Connector error:  '42000' : [microsoft][odbc microsoft access driver] undefined function " function name" in expression . database vendor code 3102